# Open vpn configuration & setup

Tags: xubuntu

**How to install & setup the openVPN ?**
*I am using Linux Mint 18.1 ( Cinnamon)*

Comment: Linux Mint is not Ubuntu and is therefore considered off-topic for this site. You might consider asking your question on the [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) instead, which supports all Linux distros.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can run in the terminal: `sudo apt-get install openvpn`

But it's probably already installed, if it's Linux Mint 18.1. (I am not sure, because it is tagged Xubuntu.)

Did you start an account with OpenVPN? Their website will probably be able to provide you more information on connecting your account. But you can run `openvpn --help` in the terminal for options.

Comment: sir i have downloaded the .ovpn file but unable to import the file in network settings> vpn> import file option.                    Result:
Cannot import VPN connection
The filen vpn.ovpn could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information
Error: configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element(line 78)